# What are the differences between Port-mirroring and Ping-echoing?

Tags: networking, monitoring, port-forwarding, router

I am building a communication network using Ethernet between a mobile platform and a base/controller station. So packets shall be sent from the mobile platform to the base station only. So, I need to check the connectivity between these two points maybe by using Port-mirroring or Ping-echoing. I have been looking for for the better way to create a realtime connectivity checking with providing detailed network analysis if possible.

Thanks for your time to reply.

Comment: How exactly are you using Ethernet (i.e., based on a physical connection, some sort of cable) for communication between a mobile platform and a base station? Does the mobile platform lug the cable around, and you are afraid it will get broken? Are you sure there's not some wireless involved somewhere?

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for your comment. It is based on Ethernet physical connection. I am afraid that the connection fails, and I would like to create either Ping-Echoing or Port-mirroring, but I I would like to know what are the pros and cons if possible.

Comment: Ok, next question: Port mirroring means to completely "copy" the complete traffic from one port (of a switch) to some other port (on the same switch). How is that going to help check the connectivity, if there's a single cable connecting the base station with the mobile platform? Or do you mean something else? It certainly does help with network analysis, of course - you'll be able to see the exact traffic on the cable.

Comment: @dirkt I agree. So for the connectivity: I will need to check if there is no traffic, I can assume that there is a problem. But only if I ensure that there is always going to be SOME traffic. So if the mobile platform sends something at least every second, with mirroring I can check whether the base station has not received something for more than one second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you have answered your own question:

- If you have to ensure that there's always some traffic, either base station and mobile client need to regularly ping each other, or a third party that's also connected to the network via a switch needs to ping them regularly.
- If the connectivity check is done inside the base station and the mobile client, you don't need a switch. If there's a third party who does the monitoring, you need a switch. If this third party also wants to analyze network traffic, you need to mirror the network traffic to the port of the third party.

So, port-mirroring and ping-echoing are totally different things. The first applies only if there's a third party doing the monitoring, the second applies only if no constant traffic can be ensured. Nothing prevents you from using both.

**Edit**:

- Latency: You'll get the smallest latency if you're both passively monitoring (existing traffic) and ping in small intervals. Pings may be dropped because of collisions, so you need several failed pings before you can be sure the connection is broken. But if they get dropped, there will be other traffic, so if you monitor this passively, it shouldn't be a problem.

I'm not sure what you expect with respect to security and real-time measurements. Pings and ping replies are nearly instantanous, as well as passive traffic monitoring. For security considerations, you'll need to explain the sitation in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i would like to ask you as well regarding their architectures based on their latency, security, and real-time measurements. Which one is better to use?